# Workflow Manager Config won't recognize open ports

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Good afternoon, all!

I'm trying to get Workflow Manager installed so I can do some dev.  The Configuration for Service Bus section of the Config Wizard has a problem seeing the open ports on the firewall for HTTPS port 9355 and Internal Communication Port Range 9000-9004.  These ports are specifically open in Windows Firewall.  I also tried setting this up with the "Enable firewall rules on this computer" tick boxes unchecked.  The Summary page shows the value FALSE, but I still get "port 9355 is blocked" and "port 9002 is blocked" . Netstat shows the ports in listening mode.

The installation string said it finished successfully, but I have some errors in the Application logs referring to the Service Bus Message Broker.  Apparently it crashed, but I restarted both the Message Broker and the Service Bus Gateway.  Don't know if these are significant, but it deserved mentioning.

Thanks to all for looking!

Gregg

Comment: Have you disabled the firewall completely and checked behavior.  Do you have any anti-malware running?  If so disable that and try again and see if the error is the same.

Comment: Good afternoon, Jesus!  I was able to get things going with Microsoft Support.  Ended up uninstalling and reinstalling in a particular order.  Workflows are running now.  Thanks!

Comment: It's a helpful explanation and solution for **[Port number specified for internal communication Port Range is blocked](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/workflow-manager-port-is-blocked/)**